# Where is iOS Background Thread Being Called From - Stack Trace Via Instruments

Tags: ios, performance, instruments

I am trying to figure out why my program is hanging at one point. I know full well about the hefty call I make on the main thread but I don't know what the dispatch queue is that accounts for nearly half of the time. How can I trace where that call is coming from? Here is a screenshot from Instruments:

[image]